# Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan. Error: *** Deployment Failed ***

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle, metamask

I got the error below when I ran the following command `truffle migrate --network linea_goerli` to deploy on the Linea network.

I am using the solidity version: `0.8.21`, and I have redeployed it multiple times with no luck, even though I am passing the correct argument in the constructor when deploying the smart contract.

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'linea_goerli'
> Network id:      59140
> Block gas limit: 61000000 (0x3a2c940)


1_deploy_contract.js
====================

   Deploying 'SendMessage'
   -----------------------
 *** Deployment Failed ***

"SendMessage" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.


Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.


Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"SendMessage" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:330:1
Truffle v5.11.2 (core: 5.11.2)
Node v18.13.0
```

Deploy Script:

```
const SendMessage = artifacts.require("SendMessage");

const gatewayAddress = "0xe432150cce91c13a887f7D836923d5597adD8E31";
// Gas Service Contract address
const gasService = "0xbE406F0189A0B4cf3A05C286473D23791Dd44Cc6";

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  // Arguments are: contract
  deployer.deploy(SendMessage, gatewayAddress, gasService);
};
```

How do I fix this? The same contract works well with hardhat.

Comment: I tried to redeploy multiple times, but it didn't work; then I figured it was an error due to the compiler version at `0.8.21` I had to downgrade it to 0.8.9, and it worked! 

`compilers: { solc: { version: "0.8.9", // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version) // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false) // settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion //  optimizer: { //    enabled: false, //    runs: 200 //  }, //  evmVersion: "byzantium" // } }, },`